# laravel: data to be displayed on page using drop down list

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing a drop down menu list to display a list of hotels from my system. I currently have the following code which when i click submit, nothing is happening (no data displayed).

Does anyone know how i can potentially display data once i press submit ?

The output of this is currently showing the hotel id in the URL E.G (http...search?title=3) showing that it is partly working, however i do i manage to display it on my page ?

Search.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts.app')
@section('content')  

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="distance" id="distance" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
        <option value="">Choose an item</option>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <option value="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->distance }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
</div>
@if($request)

                <p>{{ $request->title }}</p>
                <p>{{ $request->distance }}</p>
                <img src="{{$request->image}}" height = 200 width =200>

    @endif
```

SearchController.php

```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
       $posts = Post::all();

       $selectedPost = $request->has('distance')
           ? Post::find($request->distance)
           : null;

       return view('Pages.search', [
           'posts' => $posts,
           'request' => $selectedPost
       ]);
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
       // This will return all request data to your screen.
       return $request->all();
       return view('Pages.search');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic to retrieve data should be placed inside the controller, the view only shows the data.

> search.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="post_id" id="title" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
        <option value="">Choose an item</option>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <option value="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
</div>

@if($post)
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Hotel name</th>
                <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <td>{{ $post->distance }}</td>
                <th>Images</th>
                <td>{{ $post->image }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
@endif
```

> App/Http/Controller/SearchController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller {

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        $selectedPost = $request->has('post_id')
            ? Post::find($request->post_id)
            : null;

        return view('Pages.search', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'post' => $selectedPost
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // This will return all request data to your screen.
        return $request->all();
        return view('Pages.search');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maarten please see the updated code, i didnt include my controller, maybe you can see the controller i already have and make any changes, thanks

Comment: Hi @maartenDev no luck this did not work sorry. No error message but the information did not change/show on my page

Comment: Hi @maartenDev i got it working !!! i changed the 'post' => $selectedPost to 'request' => $selectedPost. I then assisgned the variable to    <td>{{ $request->title }}</td> in my search.blade.

Comment: you wont be able to help with a slight issue, how would i remove duplicate entries on my drop down list. For example the value is appearing twice in the menu

Comment: Are the values stored twice in the database?

Comment: Well, originally they werent, however i have changed the values on purpose to see if they would both appear and they did, i want to select that singular value and return all the posts matching that value.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve? Should it like only return the first value that matches? Or only show unique items in the dropdown?

Comment: I am basing my drop down menu on the distance to the hotel. So from the drop down list if i select the value 30, it should return all posts that have distance 30, I.E. a one to many relationship type of thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208362/discussion-between-maartendev-and-cutesengh).

Comment: hi @maartenDev are you still there